# Change Photoset Max Width to 340px?

Tags: tumblr

Having some issues trying to get my photoset width to 340px without messing up the way the smaller photos in the photoset display. http://d.pr/icuf

```
{block:Photoset}
              {block:IndexPage}
              <div class="photo_set">
              <div class="header">
                  <a href="{Permalink}"><h1>photoset</h1></a>
                  {block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}">
                  <div class="note">{NoteCountWithLabel}</div></a>
                  {/block:NoteCount}
                  <div class="clear"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="view">
                  <a href="{Permalink}">
                  <div class="link">View Photoset ↦</div></a>
              </div>
              {Photoset-250}
              </div>{/block:IndexPage}

              {block:PermalinkPage}
              <div class="perma_width">{Photoset-500}</div>
              {/block:PermalinkPage}
      {/block:Photoset}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get a 340px width using Tumblr's default code. You have two options:

1) Don't use Tumblr's `{Photoset}` tags and display each photo individually with `{block:Photos}...{/block:Photos}` and style them as you want.

2) Use a plugin like this: https://github.com/PixelUnion/Extended-Tumblr-Photoset (full disclosure, it's something that I wrote)